# Failed to create query method when using @IdClass composite primary key

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am attempting to create a simple `existsBy` query in a JPA repository using Spring Boot Data JPA. I am getting an error when Spring tries to create the method at runtime. `existsBy` seems to be the only type of query it is having trouble with. It can create `findBy` queries just fine. All Spring Boot dependencies in my application are using version 1.5.10.RELEASE.

Here I have a simple User class that uses an `@IdClass` for a composite primary key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MASTER_USER")
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TOS_ID")
    private String tosId;

    private boolean isCool;

   // getters and setters
}

public class UserPk implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TOS_ID")
    private String tosId;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Then in my User repository I want an `existsByIsCool` method to return true if there are any cool users.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UserPK> {

    ...

    boolean existsByIsCool(boolean isCool);

}
```

Everything compiles fine, but I get the following error when running the application. Just for some stack trace context, this is inside of a Spring REST API that uses Spring Security.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myDaoAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract boolean com.acme.data.dao.UserRepository.existsByIsCool(boolean)! null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.acme.api.MyApiApplication.main(MyApiApplication.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract boolean com.acme.data.dao.UserRepository.existsByIsCool(boolean)! null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract boolean com.acme.data.dao.UserRepository.existsByIsCool(boolean)! null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract boolean com.acme.data.dao.UserRepository.existsByIsCool(boolean)! null
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:449)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:222)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:133)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:72)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

The relevant parts are

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract boolean com.acme.data.dao.UserRepository.existsByIsCool(boolean)! null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:187)
```

Now, if I remove the composite primary key `@IdClass` and only use a single field as the `@Id`, then everything works fine, no issues creating the method.

**Edit**

I've tracked this down to a bug report. If you are experiencing this issue, please vote on it here
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1130

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with spring, but spring-data Repository interface has certain prefixes which are used to build queries, `exists` is not among them, at least in versions before Spring Data JPA 1.11.

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-11-0 https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: If you are indeed using older spring-data-jpa then another option is building your own query with  `@Query()`

Comment: Your comment led me to find this, relevant! https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-851?focusedCommentId=152172&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-152172
So it seems that it should be supported because the 1.5.10 starter uses spring-data-jpa 1.11.0

Comment: If you are using services layer against repositories layer (if not, I strongly advice to do so), then you can change your method `existsByIsCool` to `countByIsCool` and your Service would have `existsByIsCool { return > 0 }`. A bit cheating, but gets a desired effect in my opinion.